# android picasso doesn't work when application start

Tags: android, timer, picasso

I am using picasso with timer to change url of image in MainActivity oncreate() so first time i open application it doesn't work i navigate to other activity and return to main it works

i am printing 'test' in Runnable and it is working

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        parent_view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Image_view =  findViewById(R.id.adv_image);

        global = (GlobalVariable) getApplication();
        db = new DatabaseManager(this);
        db_user = new DatabaseUserManager(this);

        final String [] url = {"https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fh260/back_pic/00/03/20/63561dc0bf71922.jpg",
                "https://placeit-assets.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/landing-pages/make-a-twitch-banner2/Twitch-Banner-Blue-1024x324.png",
                "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgYdaf-JhDiFVeQjL6ZRskiF1CRADiJfgDKI3PKBfCMrnnPcHP"};

        final String [] paths = {"https://www.google.com/",
                "https://www.youtube.com/",
                "https://www.facebook.com/"};

        Timer adtimer = new Timer();
        adtimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int count = 0  ;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                count++;
                if(count >= url.length )
                count = 0;

                ActivityMain.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("test");
                        Picasso.get()
                                .load(String.format(url[count]))
                                .fit()
                                .into(Image_view);
                    }
                });
                Image_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(paths[count]);
                        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                        startActivity(launchBrowser);
                    }
                });
            }
        } , 200 , 5000);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have waited for the TimerTask to run the code? I can't see a reason why this should work after onResume but not from the very beginning.

Comment: Time is running and i can see print in log but i got ImageView empty until i navigate and return back to MainActivity

Comment: It may have to do with the way Picasso handles imaging. Maybe it doesn't work correctly inside a runnable?
Try passing the image without the library and tell me what you see. :)

Comment: i get it  i put constraint layout as img parent maybe because of it